# Bootstrap 4: remove columns margin gutter

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 in an Angular project and i have noticed that the framework automatically put some left margin when using the `.col` class.
The problem is that i can't remove that margin because even the inspector tell me that margin is `none`.

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF8CD.png)

How do i do?

Answer (score 4):

Add the `no-gutters` class to the `.row`.

That removes the gutter.

Alternatively, you can use the classes `p-0` for "padding:0" or `m-0` for "margin:0" on the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class .noMargin to any div which should have zero margin , define it in css with 'margin:0px',

You can use the same class wherever you want.

Or

If you don't want to do it by yourself you can use no-gutters in .row class